# How to edit and save documents on an iPhone (iOS 14.4) using MS Word without "signing in" to Microsoft?

Tags: iphone, ios, ms-office

When I create and write a document on my laptop using Word 2003 on Windows 10 Pro and then save it on my iPhone which runs iOS 14, I can read it using Word on the iPhone but that program asks me to "sign in", presumably to a Microsoft account, if I want to edit and save it. Is there a way to do this without "signing in" to Microsoft, i.e. being truly offline?

Comment: Microsoft Office products for iOS require a login, (copy protection) so they can verify you have an up to date, valid, license. Have you tried opening it with Pages? Depending on the document, Pages may do an acceptable job with MS Word files and its free.

Comment: @SteveChambers - Ah, I see. Thanks for this. So Microsoft insist on users of Word on iOS logging in for verification. I can open .doc files with both Pages and Collabora. They're good but each has one or two annoyances I'm trying to work around. I was hoping Word might be the program to use since I'm already using a version of it on the laptop with the same files.

Comment: Yah, MS wants to track you (so you have to log in) for minimal features in the app or pay for full access to all they offer on iOS. I **just** got Office 365 through work and that is what it seems to be, but I am a newbie with this particular app, so maybe someone else has better info...